# importing variables from multiple files

Tags: python, import

I have data from an experiment, where the data for each trial is saved a python file with some variables. Each trial is saved in a different directory, but with the same file name. My main goal is to parse this data.

Right now I'm able to import a single file using `__import__` by doing a `sys.path.append`, and then importing the file.

However, even if I do a `sys.path.remove` and then change the path and try to import a new file (same dame, different directory), the original file is remembered. I have tried using `del module_name` to delete the first file.

Is there a standard way of doing this? I can make it work by using `exec`, but I'd prefer not to do it that way.

Comment: _Is there a standard way of doing this?_ Put all your python data files in one directory, and add that directory to the path.

Comment: _Each trial is saved as a different file name_ ... _try to import a new file (same dame, different directory)_ These two statements disagree.

Comment: Sorry about that, i mean different directories, same name.

Comment: You should really just find a better way to serialize your data. You are abusing the module system for very little apparent gain, as far as I can tell. Just use `pickle` or `shelve` or even JSON. In fact, I would say if you really want to keep using this approach, then you are better off just using `exec`. It is much better than fiddling around with imports in arcane ways.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the data isn't in an ideal format. It is the output of logview in PETSc. I wasn't able to find a better way to save the outputs, so if anyone has suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are stored in a dict named `sys.modules` when you `import` them.

So when you call `import XXX` again, it will load from cache.

The simplest way to remove cache is pop it from `sys.modules`.

But I want to suggest another way:

Use `importlib` lib.

```
import importlib.util

# load .py file info:
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name_of_your_file_without_ext,
                                              path_of_your_file)
# create module:
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
# init module:
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

This will **NOT** cache the module in `sys.modules`.

Then you can do whatever you want to `module`.